# Mongoose array query

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to query my database for a specific array element thats contained inside a user model, the schema looks a bit like this:

```js
const schemaUser = new mongoose.Schema({

    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },

    email: {type: String, unique: true},

    password: { type: String, required: true},

    accounts: [{
        id : String,
        account_name : String,
        name : String,
        password : String,
        description: String
    }]

});
```

How could I go about selecting a specific account out of the "accounts" array using its custom id shown (not the Mongodb one) that is also contained inside a specific users object?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for a record that contains a specific account depending on its id, you could use :

```
userSchema.findOne({ "accounts.id": { $eq: id }})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, is there any way I could also delete that specific dict located inside the array after finding it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question revolves around finding the user based on an array, rather than querying the mongoDB, you could use the `array.find()` method to return the object you want, based on the `id` property.

More about `array.find()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

**Example:**

```js
const accountList = [
    {
        id : 1,
        account_name : 'account_one',
        name : 'John Doe',
        password : 'asdhui"#¤7aysdg',
        description: 'dummy account #1'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        account_name : 'account_two',
        name : 'Jane Doe',
        password : 'asdhui"#¤7aysdg',
        description: 'dummy account #2'
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        account_name : 'account_three',
        name : 'Derrick Johnson',
        password : 'asdhui"#¤7aysdg',
        description: 'dummy account #3'
    }
];

console.log(accountList.find(account => account.id === 1));
```

Note that the `array.find()` method will only return the first instance. If you want to do other types of lookups and return a list of users based on something that isn't unique, then you'd have to use the `array.filter()` method instead.

---

In the case you did mean to query the mongoDB, you could query for the field value of the specific document directly by specifying the field you want, followed by the `$eq` operator and value.

**Example:**

```
userSchema.findOne({ "id": { $eq: value } })
```

`value` being the specific `id` of the user you want.

More about the `$eq` operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/).